# get a random set of photos using instagram API

Tags: jquery, api, instagram, photos

I'm using jquery to access my photos using the instagram API. I use the endpoint url

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'+id+'/media/recent?callback=?&count=4`

where "`id`" is substituted with my id on instagram.

This works fine by loading the four most recent images in my feed. However, I want 4 random pictures from my photo collection to load each time I query the URL. Is there a way to do using the API. I could not find a "random" endpoint or example on the instagram site, not could I find anything forum they have for developers.

My back up plan would be to grab more and then randomize the pictures i show client side.

Comment: Try random instead of recent ... ?

Comment: thanks, tried that before but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Instagram endpoint that supports a random parameter, at least one that is documented. You would need to retrieve several media objects and select a random set on your end.

Maybe you could mix things up a little using max and min timestamps.

Comment: was trying o avoid a hack, but I guess I may have to. I find it odd though that it wouldnt be available.

Comment: @Jarrod I've had to do the same thing for my Youtube video feed on my own website. I used the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle algorithm.

Comment: I wrote my own randomizer method (using the algorithm mentioned above). I grab my entire instagram feed and shuffle it. Then I select the top 4 (or whatever amount you need). Works like a champ.